# Unexpected behavior using VALUES() with IF() in MySQL INSERT..ON DUPLICATE

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand how the `VALUES()` function works with `IF()` conditions in MySQL `INSERT` queries. I'm working with some complex queries that are failing, either due to incorrect understanding on my part or it's a MySQL documentation issue.

Here is a simple example using a table with a unique `id` and value `v`:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `v` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

```
mysql> insert into test set id=1, v=if(1 > v, 1, v) on duplicate key update v=values(v);
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+----+---+
| id | v |
+----+---+
|  1 | 1 |
+----+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This inserts v=1 as expected.

However, when I use the following query, the value of v becomes 0 which I didn't expect.

```
mysql> insert into test set id=1, v=if(0 > v, 0, v) on duplicate key update v=values(v);
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+----+---+
| id | v |
+----+---+
|  1 | 0 |
+----+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I assumed that since the value of `v` is `1` and `if(0 > v, 0, v)` condition fails, the assignment of `v` would retain its existing value and so do `v=values(v)`. Therefore, I expected the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to also retain the value.

Clearly my understanding is incorrect. Can someone explain why the value of `v` is changed to 0 in the second query? I would like to better understand how VALUES() and IF() interact in this context.

Update: the following is from the MySQL documentation

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
> In assignment value expressions in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause,
> you can use the VALUES(col_name) function to refer to column values
> from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
> statement. **In other words, VALUES(col_name) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY
> UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted,
> had no duplicate-key conflict occurred.**

Comment: *I assumed that since the value of v is 1* ?? Where you have taken this from? When INSERT starts then `v` contains zero (not 1) which is defined by `DEFAULT '0'`. So the condition `0 > v` returns FALSE, and second alternative expression (which is `v`) is selected by `IF()`. And zero value is not altered. PS. Why do you use string-type default values for numeric columns?

Comment: Please read the post properly. value of v is 1 after the first query.

Comment: :facepalm: Your 2nd INSERT inserts **another** row with is **not** related to the row inserted by 1st query. And, of course, the value stored in previous INSERT is not taken into account.

Comment: How it is not related? It's on the same table.

Comment: You appears to be making random comments instead of helping and then marking it to close. Can you please avoid this question so other people can help.

Comment: Oh, I understand. You think that ODKU causes the query to refer to existent row... but when SET is working then the duplicate is not detected yet. So `v` refers on the default value. And when the duplication is detected then the expression from SET clause is not re-calculated, and VALUES() uses the value which is obtained based on default value. I.e. new row is compiled by SET completely, and after this it is checked for duplicate violation, then VALUES() refers to this row.

Comment: ok, thanks, shouldn't values(v) be taken from this expression? `if(0 > v, 0, v)`

Comment: I believe you need to copy-paste the show expression in the set clause like `update v = if (0 > column(v), ...)`. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) about the value of `values` is somewhat ambiguous any you're interpreting it in your own way.

Comment: @SalmanA, I understand that but I thought the purpose of values() in on duplicate update was to avoid that. Since the original query is complex, I tried avoid it

Comment: This is from mysql documentation = "In assignment value expressions in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause, you can use the VALUES(col_name) function to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement"

Comment: What is the actual purpose of your question? Writing the query with minimal repetition?

Comment: @SalmanA, purpose is to understand why it is not working as expected. As per MySQL documentation, " In other words, VALUES(col_name) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred." which is not ambiguous. It clearly says that values() refer to to the value of col_name that would be inserted

Comment: @Ketu: the doc says "... refers to the value ...", it doesn't say "... refers to the _expression_ ...". The `if(...)` is evaluated (and the evaluated value is 0), then when trying to insert, a unique key constrain triggers, so MySQL falls back to the `on duplicate key ...` statement and updates the value, expect that now it is an integer with value `0`, not an expression that says "now that you have spotted a duplicate line, take the value v from that line and feed it into my expression please"

Comment: to illustrate a way to have the behavior you seem to look for: you could write `INSERT ..., v = greatest(v, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE v = greatest(v, 0)` (<- write the same _expression_ when updating)

Comment: @LeGEC, please elaborate so I can understand better. For second query, the existing value of v is 1 and hence the evaluated value of expression "v=if(0 > v, 0, v)" should be `v` and not 0 as you said.

Comment: @LeGEC, I know greatest and other ways but that's not the purpose. The purpose is to understand the logic of values() so will appreciate if you stay focus on it. The original query is far more complex, the one I described is a simplified one just to understand.

Comment: @Ketu: when MySQL reaches the point with `v = values(v)`, `values(v)` now refers to an actual computed value in some inner row computed by MySQL (e.g: an integer whose value is now `0`), not a construct that indicates "please run some computation with v" (e.g: it is _not_ the expression `if(v>0, v, 0)`). Does that make sense ?

Comment: @LeGEC, not really. I also didn't understand what you meant by "some inner row computed" If you read the MySQL documentation I quoted in original post, it says that VALUES(col_name) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred, which in this case would be `v` and not 0. So the updated value should be v (existing) and not 0 as you are suggesting.

Comment: @Ketu : if the example were simpler: `insert into test set id=1, v=2 on duplicate key update v=VALUES(v)`, what would you expect `VALUES(v)` to be ?

Comment: @LeGEC I would expect 2 in the query your posted.

Comment: (second lead was even worse)

Comment: mind elaborating?

Answer (score 0):

The very doc you quote says "... refers to the value ...", not "... refers to the expression ...".

In your example, when the `on duplicate key update ...` clause triggers, the value to insert has been computed, and is `0`.

---

If you want to have the same *expression* evaluated, repeat it in the "update" part :

```
insert into test set id=1, v=if(0 > v, 0, v)
  on duplicate key update v=if(0 > v, 0, v);
```

Comment: As far as I understand, it ***does*** refer to the expression. Only that the expression in the set clause does not refer to the existing value of column but to the default value of the column (`default 0`). If you use an expression that does not use the column e.g. `pow(2, 8)` then you get 256 in the updated column.

Comment: @LegalC, while the query you suggested may work, it defeats the purpose. The idea is to use values(), and the documentation is very clear here. The mysql doc does not distinguish between value or expression, instead it says about the end result, which is "value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred". So the documentation is all about the final value. whether it comes from the specifying the value directly or by expression.

Comment: what other progamming languages are you used to ?

Comment: say in python you write : `v = 0; values = { 'v': max(v,1) }; v = 2;  print(values['v'])`, what would you expect it to print ?

Comment: @LeGEC, The mysql documentation is clear. If you can explain and help me in terms of mysql, well and great. Else let's avoid getting into a wrong loop. Please read my comment above.

Comment: I'm mentioning the python code to say: the value is computed at step 2, and not recomputed at step 4. This is similar to how mysql behaves, and the documentation wording is compatible with that -- when it says "value", it means "the value that was computed at insert time".

Comment: "value of col_name that would be inserted" - so values means the final value here. It did't say literal value so you are assuming here.

Comment: Step 2 or 4 doesn't matter, "that would be inserted" means that the value would have been inserted in step 2, so if it was not computed, it has to be computed again in step 4. At least that's the interpretation as per the documentation.

Comment: I am not concluding that you are right or wrong, I am only saying that the behavior  is not as per the documentation.

Comment: And nowhere in the documentation, it says it can't be expression.